# Sending Emails through SendGrid API through PHP on Azure WordPress Website

Tags: php, wordpress, email, azure, sendgrid

I have a SendGrid account already and couldn't find a way to connect that to Azure so I used the first example from https://sendgrid.com/docs/Code_Examples/php.html to try and send emails. When running the file locally it works perfectly, the email gets sent and "success" is printed, but when I push to the website, no message is printed and no email is sent. FTP shows the file has not been modified on the website, it is no different than the one I have locally. Is Azure doing something that stops the connection to SendGrid?

Comment: Clarification: When "php -f (the file)" is used locally, the email is sent... it's only when it is pushed to the azure wordpress site that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Azure does not firewall connections.  You could use SMTP as well as the API.

Take a look at the this which is specific to Azure and PHP.

[Azure PHP Send Grid](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-sendgrid-php-how-to-send-email/)

Comment: My code is exactly the same as the Azure - SendGrid Web API example with the username, password, and recipient of email changed... still doesn't work

Comment: In the portal you can also enable diagnostics and then check the file which sits in the FTP area.  This may also give you a clue as well as the code level check below.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is some PHP error.
One of possible issues could be missing curl extension.

To quickly check it try to add to the beginning of your PHP script following lines:

```
<?php

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

var_dump(function_exists('curl_version'));
```

This will enable all errors and show it to your screen. Also you'll get "true" or "false" depending if CURL extension is installed.

Comment: I can't seem to find anything in the php_errors log when i FTP into the website.